# access to bitcoin node via https

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet, bitcoinlib

i have my own bitcoin testnet node over https link and when i wanna ping it via curl

*curl https://link_to node/*
I have a response like

```
JSONRPC server handles only POST requests
```

so it's mean that I can connect to the node and send requests to it, so I wanna connect to it via nodejs and bitcoin-core. and I wanna init bitcoin object like

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoin-core');
    let client = new bitcoin({
        network: 'testnet', 
        username: 'user', 
        password: 'password', 
        host: 'https://link_to_node/',
        timeout: 30000,
        port: 443
    });

    client.upTime((err, res) => {console.log(err, ' and ', res);})</i>
```

here I connected to the node and send a request about uptime of it and receive a response like

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https https:80
>          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
>        errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>        code: 'ENOTFOUND',
>        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>        hostname: 'https',
>        host: 'https',
>        port: 80 },   isOperational: true,   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',   code: 'ENOTFOUND',   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',   hostname: 'https',   host:
>   'https',   port: 80 }

So how I can connect to bitcoin node via https and bitcoin-core?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core's JSON RPC API does not support HTTPS. However you can make it (on the server) only accessible through localhost (`rpcallowip=127.0.0.1`). Tehn you could write a wrapper (PHP for example) and run this through an HTTPS web server.